# htaccess for changing index.php?ms=user to /user

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to redirect my site url's with 301 code

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php?ms=user&ms_1=name   -->  http://www.domain.com/user/name
http://www.domain.com/index.php?ms=2652&ms_1=title  -->  http://www.domain.com/2652/title
http://www.domain.com/index.php?ms=questions        -->  http://www.domain.com/questions
http://www.domain.com/index.php?ms=aaa&ms_1=bbb&ms_2=ccc      -->  http://www.domain.com/aaa/bbb/ccc
```

the stuffs after `ms` can have space and utf8 characters too

How can I  do it ?

Comment: What you have already tried?

Comment: Good to know what you want but it will be better if you show your attempts to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /index\.php\?ms=(.*)&ms_1=(.*)&ms_2=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%3/%4\? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?ms=$1&ms_1=$2&ms_2=$3 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /index\.php\?ms=(.*)&ms_1=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%3\? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?ms=$1&ms_1=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /index\.php\?ms=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%2\? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /index.php?ms=$1 [L]
```

It will change `http://www.domain.com/index.php?ms=aaa&ms_1=bbb&ms_2=ccc` into  `http://www.domain.com/aaa/bbb/ccc`, but all you to see the content of `http://www.domain.com/index.php?ms=aaa&ms_1=bbb&ms_2=ccc` etc for the other two links you have.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can enable Apache rewrite module and give rewrite rules to do it. It has regex with back-reference ability. 
A possible (cause I'm not that familiar with regex in rewrite module) ruleset could be :

```
 ReWriteRule ^/index.php?ms=(.+) /$1
 ReWriteRule ^/index.php?ms=(.+)&ms_1=(.+) /$1/$2
 ReWriteRule ^/index.php?ms=(.+)&ms_1=(.+)&ms_2=(.+) /$1/$2/$3
```

Comment: That would produce a 404 error given he wants to merely hide his ugly URL and show the pretty URL yet using the content of the ugly URL.

Comment: Oh! I see. Then ignore my answer.

Answer (score 0):

please follow the code i hope it will be help to you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?ms=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?ms=$1&ms_1=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?ms=$1&ms_1=$2&ms_2=$3 [L]
```

befor this code apache rewrite module is enable