# capture first word after / without index.php htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I want to add / slash after words that are not start with html index.php

for example :

```
www.domain.com/test  --->  www.domain.com/test/
www.domain.com/index.php?test --> Not change
www.domain.com/test/test  --> Notchange
```

I know how to add slash with htaccess but I cant figure out how to not add it at the end of url's start with index.php or have two /(url's like domain.com/test/test)

Comment: My htaccess : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033857/how-to-change-url-structure-with-301-code-q2a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(html|php)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/?$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```